# Word document amended with ~1 at the end

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, document

I tried opening a word document from File explorer and the document opens in protected view and amended with ~1 at the end. The file name is shorter now with the ~1 at the end. Any idea why this happened? FYI, I can now see the original document in file explorer and is synced but when i open it, it still opens the one with ~1 in protected view.